# Calling an api in typescript constructor throws ERROR in error TS5055

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to call a GET api to get a list of customers from a dashboard constructor like below:

```
      // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
  constructor(public addCustomerDialog: MatDialog, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private customerService: CustomerService) {
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/login';
    this.customerList = getCustomers();
  }

  getCustomers() {
    const jwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt');

        // call AJAX
    this.customerService.getCustomers(jwt).subscribe((res) => { // <---
      console.log(res);
    }, (err) => { // <---
        alert('Token expired. Need to login again!');
        this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl);
        console.log(err);
    });

  }
```

I'm getting below error:

```
ERROR in error TS5055: Cannot write file '/home/spartan/Documents/development/ktf-standalone/api/config/main.js' because it would overwrite input file.
  Adding a tsconfig.json file will help organize projects that contain both TypeScript and JavaScript files. Learn more at https://aka.ms/tsconfig.
error TS5055: Cannot write file '/home/spartan/Documents/development/ktf-standalone/api/controllers/controllerCustomer.js' because it would overwrite input file.
  Adding a tsconfig.json file will help organize projects that contain both TypeScript and JavaScript files. Learn more at https://aka.ms/tsconfig.
error TS5055: Cannot write file '/home/spartan/Documents/development/ktf-standalone/api/models/customer.js' because it would overwrite input file.
  Adding a tsconfig.json file will help organize projects that contain both TypeScript and JavaScript files. Learn more at https://aka.ms/tsconfig.
```

I have tsconfig.json file in my root folder.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

When I comment out the couple of lines in constructor, I can start my server.

Is it right way to call API in constructor? Or am I missing anything here?

Project structure:
[image]

Comment: As far as calling it in the constructor it kind of depends. You want to do as little work as possible in your constructor. You want to do just enough to get your class instantiated. So if customers are not required to get your class instantiated I would recommend doing the call in the `ngOnInit` method.

Comment: What version of TypeScript? Have you looked at [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6046) on GitHub?

Comment: Thanks Todd for your feedback, I've moved the api call in ngOnInit(). 
I'm using 2.5.3 version of typescript. 
I've also tried excluding the /api folder which isn't needed for my angular server, please refer to attached snapshot of project structure above in the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies.
I had same method name 'getCustomers' both in component.ts file and api controller.

When I typed the method name in order to call in the component.ts (dashboard.ts) visual studio imported method from api controller which i didn't notice.

When I called the correct method, my problem is solved. And certainly the discussion gave food for thought to lead the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `getCustomers` method to set the value of the `customerList` property in the `subscribe` callback. You can do it with something like:

```
this.customerService.getCustomers(jwt).subscribe(
  (res) => this.customers = res.json(),
  (err) => // handle error;
);
```

Also, IIRC, angular documentation recommends against doing much beside basic variable instantiation in the constructor. I have my components implement the `OnInit` interface and make API calls in the `ngOnInit` method require when implementing the interface.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Even after making change as per your suggestion, I'm getting same error.